# 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer and not add to a list

Tags: python, datetime

I'm defining two functions in python:

```
def download_data_ibovespa_file():
    url = 'http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/indices/download/IBOVDIA.zip'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'IBOVDIA.zip')
    with zipfile.ZipFile('IBOVDIA.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall('.')`
```

and

```
def read_ibovespa_year_file(year):
    x=pd.read_excel("IBOVDIA.XLS",sheet_name=str(year),
                   skiprows=2,nrows=31,header=None,
                   names=["Dia"]+list(range(1,13)))
    #add year variable
    x["Ano"]=year
    x = pd.melt(x, id_vars=["Ano", "Dia"],
                       var_name="mes", value_name="IBOV")

    ### manipulating date vector
    x=x.dropna()
    # set the years, months and days vectors
    dias = x["Dia"]
    meses = x["mes"]
    anos = x["Ano"]
    # list to store dates
    datas = []
# Loop to create dates vector
    for dia, mes, ano in zip(dias, meses, anos):
      # date obs for each row
      y = dt.datetime(ano, mes, dia)
      # Adiciona a data formatada ao vetor de datas
      datas.append(y.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    x["Datas"]=datas
    x = x.drop(['Ano', 'mes', 'Dia'], axis=1)
    return x
```

Then, I generate loop to storage some data frames:

```
data=[]
for i in range(1970,1972):
    data.append(read_ibovespa_year_file(i))
```

Then, it returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[55], line 3
      1 data=[]
      2 for i in range(1970,1972):
----> 3     data.append(read_ibovespa_year_file(i))

Cell In[48], line 21, in read_ibovespa_year_file(year)
     18 # Loop to create dates vector
     19     for dia, mes, ano in zip(dias, meses, anos):
     20       # date obs for each row
---> 21       y = dt.datetime(ano, mes, dia)
     22       # Adiciona a data formatada ao vetor de datas
     23       datas.append(y.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Then, I generate loop to storage some data frames

Comment: Maybe the `Dia` and `mes` are float types in Excel, try `x["mes"] = x["mes"].astype(int)` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one of those values `dias`, `meses`, or `anos` are a `float` instead of an `integer`, just convert these values to integers before creating the `datetime` object.

edit: We will also check if the date is valid before creating the datetime object

```
from calendar import monthrange

for dia, mes, ano in zip(dias, meses, anos):
    # Convert to integers
    dia = int(dia)
    mes = int(mes)
    ano = int(ano)
    
    # Check if the date is valid
    if 1 <= dia <= monthrange(ano, mes)[1]:
        # date obs for each row
        y = dt.datetime(ano, mes, dia)
        
        # Adiciona a data formatada ao vetor de datas
        datas.append(y.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: I tried that but it returns:
Cell In[73], line 26, in read_ibovespa_year_file(year)
     24 ano = int(ano)
     25 # date obs for each row 
---> 26 y = dt.datetime(ano, mes, dia)
     27 # Adiciona a data formatada ao vetor de datas
     28 datas.append(y.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

ValueError: day is out of range for month

Comment: There might be an invalid date value in your dataset, I updated my answer

Comment: now, im getting this error: ValueError:    4142 def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
   4143     """
...
    579         "does not match length of index "
    580         f"({len(index)})"
    581     ) Length of values (0) does not match length of index (114)

Comment: thank you for the support sir. In fact I was importing the data in a wrong way.